# IronPython Installation

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, ironpython, arcgis

I am attempting to install IronPython. I downloaded the stable 2.7.5 installer from here:

http://ironpython.net/download/

I ran the installer and all is well. It is not located at:

C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7

I have a previous installation of Python 2.7 from my ArcGIS installation, which packages and installs python along with it. My installation location for python is:

C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2

So, when I test and:

```
import clr
```

I receive and error:

```
ImportError: No module named clr
```

My Environment Variable Path names are all correct.

I'm just wondering if python IDLE knows where to grab IronPython, or did I install wrong?

Comment: "when I test" is pretty ambiguous. How are you starting your interpreter? What is a value of `sys.executable`? What are the headers just after interactive mode startup? Probably you are still using your old CPython interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the IronPython intepreter is `ipy.exe`. If you not starting this, you are not using `IronPython`. So you should see the application name in the window title and when starting the shell. When you use it in an IDE, you should tell the IDE that you are using IronPython, if it support it. Just setting some environment variables will not help. If you are targeting the correct directory and ipy.exe will be used, everything should work just fine.